# Questions on forred (as in fore-head)

Tags: abbreviations

1 How do you spell forred (as in fore-head)?

2 why is this not in the dictionary?

3 Is forred universally used in English speaking countries?

Comment: It's just spelled "forehead". Words often aren't spelled the way they are pronounced. A number of dictionaries mention this pronunciation: in fact, [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/forehead) gives /fɒrɪd/ before /fɔːʳhed/ (for British English), and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/forehead) gives both /ˈfɔrəd/ and /ˈfɔrˌhed/ (for American English).

Answer (score 1):

It's rarely written, and isn't a real spelling or standard.

When it is used in writing, it's as a form of [eye dialect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect), i.e. it's used in dialogue, to represent a speaker's pronunciation. I recall seeing *for'ed* and *for'ead*, but the apostrophe (to suggest the missing letters) makes them ungoogleable. Such a use is usually confined to fiction, as when transcribing real people's speech it can appear to judge their pronunciation - of course it may be necessary when describing regional speech patterns.

With redirect to your third question, no, it's not universal. I'm originally from London and my accent varies with context. In work/academic/formal circles I'd always use the proper form, but I tend to slip into a more noticeable London accent when talking to people who have strong accents of their own, and drop the *h*.

Comment: I think "forrid" was actually considered to be the "U" pronunciation of the word--in the days when people still used the concept of "U" and "non-U" English. So in that sense, it might not necessarily be considered improper--but trying to use "U" forms if you haven't grown up using them would be likely to sound affected, of course. (And also, I know plenty of people do criticize "posh" British accents, but that's usually not for the same reasons as criticism of regional accents.) Related WordReference thread: [Pronunciation: forehead](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads)

Comment: @sumelic that sounds right in a historical sense - but the last vowel has now lost its stress and is more of a schwa. The history of dropping initial *h*s may be related and has similarly complex relations to class